# How to create public and private key cordova android app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, keystore, private-key

i am using  [phonegap create keystore file](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html)

Can you please open this?

I have followed that . It has worked fine.

My question is : which is private key and public key on this?

Can you explain it ? how to open the private key and public key?

I have to use that public key in localStorage Encrpyt.

Can you please check [Encrpyt/decrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) this documentation?

can you please explain it?

Comment: Those keys have nothing to do with keystore file. You have to create them using openssl.

Comment: ya ok  but actually  should i do create a public key and private key random ?

Comment: public key and private key didn't compare ??

Comment: You will create it just once, then you will use it in your app.

Comment: you told me create a keystore or public and private key

Comment: i need public and private key for single app build

Comment: It seems like you did not read the docs on https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt . Your answer is there and it is clear enough. Please read it!

Answer (score 0):

To create a valid keystore file, just follow this tutorial, it's working very well: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html#Android%20Signing

It's edited by *phonegap build* but it's not important.

Copy/past of important part:

> 1. Download and install Java.
> 2. Set Java_Home directory (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html).
> 3. Open the command prompt (cmd.exe) as an Administrator, then Run the following command:
>
>    ***keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000***
> 4. Keytool will ask for keystore password. Enter password and confirm:
> 5. Next, keytool will ask for additional information. Supply appropriately:
> 6. Next, keytool will ask password for Alias. Return if it's the same as keystore password. Othewise enter password and confirm:
> 7. Your signing key is now ready

Comment: how to get private key?

Comment: It was created on the folder where you execute "keytool" command

Comment: @Angu is it ok. Did you find your key?